# How to get Access Token from ASP.Net Web API 2 via AngularJS $http?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I try like this:

```
$http({ method: 'POST', url: '/token', data: { username: $scope.username, password: $scope.password, grant_type: 'password' } }).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
    $scope.output = data;
}).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
    $scope.output = data;
});
```

then tried changing the grant_type to a param:

```
$http({ method: 'POST', url: '/token', data: { username: $scope.username, password: $scope.password }, params: { grant_type: 'password' } }).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
    $scope.output = data;
}).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
    $scope.output = data;
});
```

Still get the dreaded: `{"error":"unsupported_grant_type"}`

So I do what no AngularJS developer should ever do, resorted to jQuery:

```
var data = $('#regForm').serialize() + "&grant_type=password";
$.post('/token', data).always(showResponse);

function showResponse(object) {
    $scope.output = JSON.stringify(object, null, 4);
    $scope.$apply();
};
```

Which works like a champ... so my question is: how do we replicate the jQuery `$.post()` call above using AngularJS `$http()` so we can grab an access token from the OWIN middleware based /token endpoint in ASP.Net Web API 2?

Comment: your problem is solved in this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11443066/894273)

Answer (score 19):

Do this:

```
$http({
        url: '/token',
        method: 'POST',
        data: "userName=" + $scope.username + "&password=" + $scope.password + 
              "&grant_type=password"
})
```

Comment: Please note that there is no quotation mark surrounding the keys nor the values. The payload is **not** JSON.

Answer (score 18):

I think, adding the header `{headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }` to your post request would do the trick. It should be something like this:

```
$http.post(loginAPIUrl, data,
    {headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }})
```

Answer (score 6):

You are getting that error because the default implementation of the OWIN OAuth provider is expecting the post to the "/Token" service to be form encoded and not json encoded. There is a more detailed answer here [How do you set katana-project to allow token requests in json format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19645171/how-do-you-set-katana-project-to-allow-token-requests-in-json-format)

But you can still use AngularJs you just have to change the way the $http post is made. You can try the answer here if you don't mind using jquery to change your params [How can I post data as form data instead of a request payload?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11442632/how-can-i-make-angular-js-post-data-as-form-data-instead-of-a-request-payload) Hope that helps.

Comment: +1 for link to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19645171/how-do-you-set-katana-project-to-allow-token-requests-in-json-format

Answer (score 2):

You can always watch for the requests being made using the developer console in your browser and see the difference in the request.

But by looking at your jquery code `&grant_type=password` is being passed in the body not the querystring so the `$http` call should be

`$http({ method: 'POST', url: '/token', data: { username: $scope.username, password: $scope.password ,grant_type:password} }).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {`

Comment: That's what my first block of code looks like... I do that, but get back `{"error":"unsupported_grant_type"}`. I tried changing data to params, which put the variables into the querystring, but it still returns that error.

Comment: My bad i did not scroll to the end. Look at the request made using the browser dev tools and you would know the different, and maybe that details can be used here to fix it.

Comment: Yea, I was digging around in FireBug... there were a couple header differences, but I set the headers on `$http` to match, still same error. I think I'm stumped. ;(

Comment: That last part `grant_type:password`, the `password` needs to be in quotes

Answer (score 1):

Similar to achinth, but you can still use the `$http.post` method (+ data is escaped)

```
$http.post(loginUrl, "userName=" + encodeURIComponent(email) +
                     "&password=" + encodeURIComponent(password) +
                     "&grant_type=password"
).success(function (data) {
//...
```

Answer (score 0):

1) Note the URL: "localhost:55828/token" (not "localhost:55828/API/token")

2) Note the request data. Its not in json format, its just plain data without double quotes.
"userName=xxx@gmail.com&password=Test123$&grant_type=password"

3) Note the content type. Content-Type: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' (not Content-Type: 'application/json')

4) When you use javascript to make post request, you may use following:

```
$http.post("localhost:55828/token", 
    "userName=" + encodeURIComponent(email) +
        "&password=" + encodeURIComponent(password) +
        "&grant_type=password",
    {headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }}
).success(function (data) {//...
```

See screenshots below from Postman:

[Postman Request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RSl7a.png)

[Postman Request Header](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fhH7h.png)