# unsupported_grant_type when PostAsJsonAync

Tags: c#, http-post, asp.net-web-api2, httpclient

I am trying to access an ASP.NET Web API via c#. I wrote the API and I am able to access it and get a valid response using Postman. The API returns an access_token and refresh_token when presented with a `username`, `password`, and `grant_type = password`.

Here is a screen capture of the response I receive when using Postman:

[image]

However, when I try and use the following C# code:

```
var userToValidate = new UserToValidate
{
    UserName = "johndoe@mydomain.com",
    Password = "Abc123!",
    grant_type = "password"
};

using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:4321");
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
    HttpResponseMessage response = client.PostAsJsonAsync("oauth/token", userToValidate).Result;
    content = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
}
```

I get an error ...
`{"error":"unsupported_grant_type"}`

I have got to be doing something wrong on the C# side of things. What am I missing?

P.S. Using `.Result` because debugging `async` code drives me nuts

Comment: I found the solution in this SO post. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29246908/c-sharp-unsupported-grant-type-when-calling-web-api. Have to use `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` instead of JSON.

Comment: Also you can pass PostData as KeyValuePair instead of UserToValidate class   `List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> postData = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();  postData.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("grant_type",    "password"));
                postData.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("username",      userName));
                postData.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("password",      password)); `

Comment: @Paresh - Can you post that up as an answer and I will accept iy. That way there are multiple options. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can get token using JSON

```
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            var email = "xyz"
            var password = "abc";
            var clientId = "123"
            var clientSecret = "456";

            client.BaseAddress = new Uri(baseUrl);

            // We want the response to be JSON.
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

            // Build up the data to POST.
            List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> postData = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();

            postData.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("grant_type",    "password"));
            postData.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("client_id",     clientId));
            postData.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("client_secret", clientSecret));
            postData.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("username",      email));
            postData.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("password",      password));



            // Post to the Server and parse the response.
            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync("Token", postData);
            string jsonString            = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            object responseData          = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsonString);

            // return the Access Token.
            accessToken = ((dynamic)responseData).access_token;
        }

        return accessToken;
```

Answer (score 0):

The content needs to be urlencoded.
This is how it worked for me:

```
            var httpClient = new HttpClient();
            httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("X-Tenant", xTenant);
            var stringContent = String.Concat("grant_type=password&username=", HttpUtility.UrlEncode(username),
                "&password=", HttpUtility.UrlEncode(password));
            var httpContent = new StringContent(stringContent, Encoding.UTF8, "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            var postTask = httpClient.PostAsync(apiLoginUrl, httpContent);
            postTask.Wait();
            var postResult = postTask.Result;
            var content = postResult.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
            dynamic jsonRes = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(content);
            string access_token = jsonRes.access_token;
```