# WebApi 2 + Owin Use urlencoded body on token request

Tags: oauth, asp.net-web-api2, owin

In my WebAPI2 app I use OAuth authentication through Owin middleware. In order to get token client should use application/x-www-form-urlencoded body in request.

```html
 function userAccount($resource, appSettings) {
    return {
        registration: $resource(appSettings.serverPath + "/api/Account/Register", null, 
                {
                    'registerUser' : { method : 'POST'}
                }
            ),
        login : $resource(appSettings.serverPath + "/Token", null, 
                {
                    'loginUser': {
                        method: 'POST',
                        headers: {
                            'Content-Type' : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' 
                        },
                        transformRequest: function (data, headersGetter) {
                            var str = [];
                            for (var d in data) {
                                str.push(encodeURIComponent(d) + "=" + encodeURIComponent(data[d]));
                            }
                            return str.join("&"); 
                        }
                    }
                } 
            )
    }
}
```

But is there any method to override this behaviour to use raw body in json format? Instead of this: "grant_type=password&username=user&password=123456" want to use this: "{ grant_type: "password", username:"user", password="123456" }".

Appreciate any suggests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set up an action in a controller as a "proxy" method that could accept the json in the body and then call the internal method with the url encoded parameters.

Comment: @sonicbils Thank u for your answer. Shure this will do the trick but think this is still kind of workaround.

Comment: Yea, but I'm pretty sure, unless you do your own implementation, its your only option.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19645171/how-do-you-set-katana-project-to-allow-token-requests-in-json-format.