# c# asp.net Web API Owin Json Token

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-identity

Hey I just programmed a token based authentication following this [tutorial](http://www.dotnetawesome.com/2016/09/token-based-authentication-in-webapi.html).
So everything goes fine as long I send my POST request as x-www-form-urlencoded. So now my teammate needs to get the token with a json, but all he gets is "unsupported grant_type". So can I change the acceptable type for the token or do I have to find another solution?

My configuration looks like this:

```
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.UseCors(Microsoft.Owin.Cors.CorsOptions.AllowAll);
        var myProvider = new MyAuthorizationServerProvider();
        OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions options = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions
        {
            AllowInsecureHttp = true,
            TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/token"),
            AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(1),
            Provider = myProvider
        };

        app.UseOAuthAuthorizationServer(options);
        app.UseOAuthBearerAuthentication(new OAuthBearerAuthenticationOptions());

        HttpConfiguration config = new HttpConfiguration();
        WebApiConfig.Register(config);
        }
    }
```

This is how my request look like keep in mind this doesnt work with json
[image: This is how my request look like keep in mind this doesnt work with json]
And with a JSON it doesnt work:
[image]
Best regards :)

Comment: are you sending `grant_type` as `password` in your request..??

Comment: added a picture of my request in my question. Is it right so?

Comment: Yes it's correct...now use the access_token in your your header authenticate your API request...

Comment: Eg: Authorization : bearer access_token...in the header of postman

Comment: yeah I already got this but the problem is that this only works with  x-www-form-urlencoded and not with JSON

Comment: Yes...its how the api for accessing the token...is written...in web api..

Comment: so I cant change it? are there any alternatives around?

Comment: No i dont think so....but why you want to post it as JSON...??

Comment: Because the whole Rest service works with json... And my teammember only know how to send json with swift and not Form urlencoded

Comment: According to the following question/answer (which is somewhat old) it isn't possible without overloading OAuthAuthorizationServerMiddleware, unfortunately no example is provided. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19645171/how-do-you-set-katana-project-to-allow-token-requests-in-json-format

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason behind the use of application/x-www-form-urlencoded as Content-Type is simple: the OAuth2 specification (RFC 6749) requires this content type for token requests.

Any other content-type will break OAuth2 compliant clients compatibility. I advice you to not change this standard behavior.

The default implementation of `OAuthAuthorizationServerMiddleware` (more precisely the internally used [`OAuthAuthorizationServerHandler`](http://katanaproject.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth/OAuthAuthorizationServerHandler.cs)) from `Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth` just ignores the `Content-Type` header and tries to read the request body as a form anyway.

**For Another way**
, In RequestBody you can write,
**grant_type=password&username=yourUserName&password=MyPassword123**,

Also make sure after grant_type=password&username=username&password=password there is no space or line break.

[image]

Comment: yeah worked for me now... sorry that it took me so long^^